# Load related entities from a Collection in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

How do I load related entities from an already loaded Collection:

The Collection:

```
public class Ad
{
    // Primary properties
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private ICollection<Feature> _features;
    public virtual ICollection<Feature> Features
    {
      get { return _features ?? (_features = new HashSet<Feature>()); }
      set { _features = value; }
    }
}
```

The Feature:

```
public class Feature
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual ICollection<Ad> Ads { get; set; }
    public Keyword Keyword { get; set; }
}
```

The Keyword:

```
public class Keyword
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

I need to load the entity Keyword for all the Features in an Ad.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your repository class try:

```
public Ad GetAd(int id)
{
     return _database.Set<Ad>().Include(ad => ad.Features.Select(feature => feature.Keyword)).FirstOrDefault(ad => ad.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, the issue here is that I use a repository with Get,Ad,etc methods.

Comment: @Patrick, the main idea is `.Include(ad => ad.Features.Select(feature => feature.Keyword))`. Or can you show an example how your repository is implemented?